# grails keep a number of page under session

Tags: session, grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I am new to grails. I have recently used session in my controller. But for only one page. Now I want to use session for a number of pages. But I have no idea how to do it. Here is my code below which works for one page. Can anyone please help me on this ?

```
def index() {
    def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
    if (user){
        redirect(controller: 'admistratorAction', action: 'createUser')
    }else{
        redirect(controller: 'login', action: 'index')
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by using session in one page? Can you post the portion you are using session ?

Comment: @Alidad I mean that if user logged in then he can reach the createUser page otherwise not. And it's working fine by the above codes. Now I want to do it for more than one view without writting it every time. I wish you understand.

Answer (score 1):

You may be new to Grails, I hope you are not new to [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html). :)

> Session information is scoped only to the current web application
>   (ServletContext), so information stored in one context will not be
>   directly visible in another.

As long as you are in the same `ServletContext` you should be able to access session variable directly. Also look at [Servlet API](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Servlet%20API/session.html) in grails.

@Alidad- Scroll back to last question from OP.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you can take advantage of grails [filter](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html) to do the check before execution of each action.  As dmahapatro mentioned you can use session across your app to store user object and with this filter you can do a check before any action.

Something like this can help you achieve it.:

```
class SecurityFilters {
    def filters = {
        loginCheck(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            before = {
                if (!session.user)) {
                    redirect(action: 'login')
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```